# Update datatable using linq based condition using dictionary

Tags: linq

I am trying to update Datatable with the value of dictionary based on key getting matched with dictionary. Below is the code snippet. It is not getting updated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("value");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["col1"] = "key1";
        dr["value"] = "No";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["col1"] = "key2";
        dr["value"] = "Yes";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["col1"] = "key3";
        dr["value"] = "No";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        test.Add("key1", "Yes");
        test.Add("key2", "No");
        test.Add("key3", "No");


        dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["col1"] == test.Select(x => x.Key)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(y => y["value"] = "Yes");
        dt.AcceptChanges();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if it would work that way, you are updating it with `"Yes"` instead of the value from the dictionary. You're also using `Enumerable.Select` instead of `Dictionary.ContainsKey` which is the real problem.

So i think this will fix both:

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => test.ContainsKey(row.Field<string>("col1")))
    .ToList<DataRow>()
    .ForEach(row => row["value"] = test[row.Field<string>("col1")]);
```

Instead of creating that list to use `ForEach` i'd prefer a different approach:

```
var newValues = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                join kv in test on row.Field<string>("col1") equals kv.Value
                select new{ DataRow = row, NewValue = kv.Value };
foreach (var x in newValues)
    x.DataRow["col1"] = x.NewValue;
```

Comment: @Hemil: then consider to accept it. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you are looking for? 
From my understanding of your question, I have this following method to solve the problem. When I had the similar problem this helped me to resolve the Issue.

`dtNewLCM.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("col1")=="key1")
    .Select(b => b["value"] = "MyValue.")
    .ToList();`

Try this...!